# Get HTML of selected link in a Mac OS X Service

Tags: cocoa, macos, service, nspasteboard

I'm writing a Service that will be bundled with my application. The user should be able to right-click on a link in Safari (or another web browser) and call my Service and have it process the link (not just the text that gets selected when the user right-clicks).

The only thing I can't do is get the URL the link points to. The [service method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-98262) gives you an `NSPasteboard` to read from, which we'll call `pboard`.

The obvious thing to try to get the selected HTML would be `[pboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeHTML]`, but that returned nil. So I called `[pboard types]`, and it returned "public.utf8-plain-text" and NSStringPboardType. So it seems like this pasteboard only supports plain-text strings.

I tried calling `[pboard addTypes:types owner:self]` (where types is an array containing `NSPasteboardTypeHTML` and nil), but it made no difference when I called `stringForType:`.

Can I somehow extract HTML from the pasteboard when `[pboard types]` only returns plain string types? Am I able to control what gets put onto the pasteboard and/or what gets read from it when my Service gets called?